# Handling Multiple ids in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have following code:

```
<div class="topPagination">
<select id="itemsPage" onClick="changeItems(this.value);">
<option value="0">12 Items per Page</option>
<option value="100">View All</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
<div class="bottomPagination">
<select id="itemsPage" onClick="changeItems(this.value);">
<option value="0">12 Items per Page</option>
<option value="100">View All</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
   function changeItems(itemsPage) {
         want to get the id of the current <select> box.
}
</script>
```

how to get the id of the current  box. like if select top select box or if i select bottom  box.
Please help me to find a solution. I know with same ids is not the porper coding standard. But i have a situation like this.

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate ID's, ID's are supposed to be unique as they Identify a specific element.

Comment: Yes i know that. But i have a situation like this.<select id="itemsPage" onClick="changeItems(this.value);">
<option value="0">12 Items per Page</option>
<option value="100">View All</option>
</select>..this snippet of code is present in a jsp and i included it two times in same parent JSP.

Comment: Duplicating IDs will cause problems when using javascript.

Comment: Can you change from using ID's to a class?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid HTLM code, all ids should be unique

But anyway you can use this code to get second checkbox

```
document.querySelectorAll('checkbox')[1];
```

if you need to browse through specific checkboxes, set them all some special class and use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.special_checkbox')[1];
```

Comment: Checkbox? shouldn't this be `select` ? `document.querySelectorAll('select')[1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you "want to get the id of the current  box", it will always be "itemsPage".

Having 2 objects in the DOM with the same ID is not valid HTML.

However, if you can change the DOM but can't change the IDs for some reason, you could do something like this:

```
<select id="itemsPage" onClick="changeItems(this);">
```

and then make your function:

```
function changeItems(select) {
    // "select" is your element
    // "select.value" is your value (that used to be passed in as "itemsPage"
}
```

Ultimately you should try and change one of the IDs, or use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to substitute duplicate `id`s ; `data-id="itemsPage-1"` for first `id=itemsPage` ; `data-id="itemsPage-2"` for second`id=itemsPage` ; pass selected element `dataset.id` at `onClick` event `onClick="changeItems(this.value, this.dataset.id);"`

```js
function changeItems(itemsPage, id) {
 console.log(itemsPage, id)
}
```

```html
<div class="topPagination">
  <select data-id="itemsPage-1" onClick="changeItems(this.value, this.dataset.id);">
    <option value="0">12 Items per Page</option>
    <option value="100">View All</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
<div class="bottomPagination">
  <select data-id="itemsPage-2" onClick="changeItems(this.value, this.dataset.id);">
    <option value="0">12 Items per Page</option>
    <option value="100">View All</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what it is you're trying to but this is a shot in the dark.

If you can change from using `id` to `class` this will work just fine.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var PageItems=document.getElementsByClassName('itemsPage');
 for(var i=0; i<PageItems.length; i++){
  //Set Event Listeners for each element using itemsPage class name
 PageItems[i].addEventListener('change',changeItems,false);
 }
}
function changeItems(){
  // New selected index
var Selected=this.selectedIndex;
var changeItems=document.getElementsByClassName('itemsPage');
 for(var i=0; i<changeItems.length; i++){
      //Change all select options to the new selected index.
  changeItems[i].selectedIndex=Selected;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="topPagination">
<select class="itemsPage">
<option value="0">12 Items per Page</option>
<option value="100">View All</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
<div class="bottomPagination">
<select class="itemsPage">
<option value="07">12 Items per Page</option>
<option value="100">View All</option>
</select>
</div>
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!